# how to retain monotonically increasing values of a one dimensional array

Tags: arrays, matlab, vectorization

Lets say i have a matrix,

```
x=[1,2,3,5,4,6,6,7,4,2,3,4,5,6,10,12,4,5,43,23,45,34,54,78];
```

Now, I want to create a new matrix where i want to know the indices and values, of elements whose value is higher than (not equal to but strictly larger than) all the previous ones.

so, the array i am looking for is,

```
y=[1,2,3,5,6,7,10,12,43,45,54,78];
```

because other numbers are just noise, and also the indices corresponding to these values in the vector x.

One more point is that i would like to avoid looping over the array, as my actual data is huge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using `cummax` to compute the running max:

```
cm = cummax(x);
ind = [1,find(x(2:end) > cm(1:end-1))+1];
y = x(ind);
```

Adapting the method from Divakar (until Divakar posts it if desired):

```
ind = find([true diff(cummax(x))>0]);
y = x(ind);
```

Comment: Using `logical indexing` might be more efficient: `y = x([true diff(cm)>0])`.

Comment: @Divakar Oops, I was in a hurry when i answered this ques.. didn't understand quite well or check it with the result given in the question. I guess `cummax` would be perfect for this. Thanks for pointing it out.  deleted my ans :)

Comment: @Divakar, good point, thanks!. I added your approach to the answer as it looks cleaner to me and was a little faster on a test case with about 12k elements. I'll remove it if you want to add it as an answer yourself.

Comment: That was just a minor improvement, so you must keep it! That `cummax` was a great idea by the way!!